# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_hex') Next js buyNft

Tags: next.js, blockchain, web3js, nft

so I am building an nft marketplace  and everything is good with creating nft .. etc but when attempting to buy an nft I get this error :

> ethers.umd.js?e6ac:4395 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_hex')

Here is the code snippet:

```
const buyNft = async (nft) => {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal();
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect();
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection);
    const signer = provider.getSigner();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      MarketAddress,
      MarketAddressABI,
      signer
    );

    const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(nft.price.toString(), "ether")

console.log(price)
// code stops here
    const transaction = await contract.createMarketSale(nft.tokenId, {
      value: price,
    });

    await transaction.wait();

  };
```

when debugging seems that the code stops before the transaction constant.
when console .log the price I get this:

[image]

I tried to remove the toString method, also tried to spread the price object in transaction variable like this value:{...price} but still didn't work

Comment: use `toString()` method for the logged bigNumber. it will extract the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createMarketSale()` first agument expects a `BigNumber` instance (or a `string`ified number that it would convert to `BigNumber`).

When you pass it `undefined`, it throws the error mentioned in your question.

**Solution:** Make sure that your `nft.tokenId` is either a `BigNumber` or `string` - not `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you !  actually it should be nft.TokenId wih capital T  not a small one .